# How to order by a multiselected value with Criteria API

Tags: java, jpa, criteria-api

I'm trying to create a generic ordering and filtering abstraction on my backend, but some values on the web CRUD can be arbitrarily complex so, in some cases, we resorted to using subqueries. The query I'm trying to generate is in this format:

```
SELECT f, (SELECT COUNT(r.id) FROM Bar b WHERE b.foo = e) c
  FROM Foo f
  ORDER BY c
```

When creating the query I'm unable to reproduce that. The subquery is repeated in the WHERE clause, for some reason. This is the error I'm getting:

```
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected AST node: query
[select generatedAlias0, (select count(generatedAlias1) from example.Bar as generatedAlias1
  where generatedAlias0=generatedAlias1.foo) from example.Foo as generatedAlias0
  order by (select count(generatedAlias1) from example.Bar as generatedAlias1
    where generatedAlias0=generatedAlias1.foo) asc]
```

Excerpt from my query code:

```java
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Tuple> query = cb.createTupleQuery();
Root<T> root = query.from(Foo.class);

Subquery<Long> subquery = query.subquery(Long.class);
Root<?> subqueryRoot = subquery.from(Bar.class);

Expression<Long> count = cb.count(subqueryRoot);
subquery.select(count);
subquery.where(cb.equal(root, subqueryRoot.get("foo")));

query.multiselect(root, subquery.getSelection());
query.orderBy(cb.asc(subquery));
```

Comment: Try reusing the expression from subquery.getSelection() in both the multi select and cb.asc() arguments

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work: the generated query and the error are the same :(

Comment: Post the entities, so it is difficult to see a solution.

So there is what seems strange to me is in the code "subquery.where (cb.equal (root, subqueryRoot.get (" foo ")));" where you compare a table with a field, root would be the FOO table but you compare it with the foo column of the BAR table, you should for example compare the ID of the FOO table with the FOO field of the BAR table

Answer (score 0):

Even if you use CriteriaAPI you can take advantage of other alternatives for sorting. I have not managed to sort by the result of the subquery but you could do one of the following:

JAVA 8

```
return entityManager.createQuery(cq).getResultList().stream()
        .sorted(Comparator.comparing(YourObject::getCount))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

ALL VERSIONS

```
List<YourObjet> list = entityManager.createQuery(cq).getResultList();
Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<YourObjet>(){
        @Override
        public int compare(YourObjet o1, YourObjet o2) {
            return o1.getCount().compareToIgnoreCase(o2.getCount());
        }
});
```

Sure there are more options, but Java 8 is really optimal